# How to match any combination of letters using regex?

Tags: javascript, java, html, regex, perl

How can I match letters a,b,c once in any combination and varying length like this:

The expression should match these cases:

```
abc
bc
a
b
bca
```

but should not match these ones:

```
abz
aab
cc
x
```

Comment: So at most only one of each letter can appear?

Comment: yes, the letter can only appear once.

Comment: This is duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664194/how-can-i-find-repeated-characters-with-a-regex-in-java

Comment: @AimonBustardo, this is not a dup of the question you referenced. That one states, "I am only looking for characters that are repeated immediately...".

Comment: This is a dup of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60575231/is-there-a-way-regex-will-match-all-the-combinations-of-the-tokens-in-operat/60575446#60575446) posted March 7, 2020. :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
\b(?!\w*(\w)\w*\1)[abc]+\b
```

You can use this pattern with any set and size, just replace `[abc]` with desired set...

---

*[Example](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5Cb%28?!%28?:.%5CB%29*%28.%29%28?:%5CB.%29*%5C1%29%5Babc%5D%2b%5Cb&input=test%20a%20b%20c%20ab%20abd%20abc%20acb%20aab%20baa%20cab%20gac%20cga%20bba%20cba%20aa%20bb%20bc%20ab%20test%0A):*

[image]

(above output is from [myregextester](http://myregextester.com/index.php))

Comment: For continuous string "abcbac", this method could not match both "abc" and "bac". Anyway, this is still very cool. 

The first part (?!(?:.\B)*(.)(?:\B.)*\1) tries to find a starting position such that from the starting position to \newline, there is no duplication. 

Then from the starting position, it tries to match [abc]+

Answer (score 6):

```
^(?=([^a]*a?[^a]*)$)(?=([^b]*b?[^b]*)$)(?=([^c]*c?[^c]*)$)[abc]{1,3}$
```

This [**works**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28%3F%3D%28%5B%5Ea%5D%2aa%3F%5B%5Ea%5D%2a%29%24%29%28%3F%3D%28%5B%5Eb%5D%2ab%3F%5B%5Eb%5D%2a%29%24%29%28%3F%3D%28%5B%5Ec%5D%2ac%3F%5B%5Ec%5D%2a%29%24%29%5Babc%5D%7B1%2C3%7D%24&input=abc%0Aab%0Aac%0Aab%0Aacb%0Aabb%0Aaa%0Abb%0Acaa%0Acbc) with [**lookaheads**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead).

It includes this pattern in three variations: `(?=([^a]*a?[^a]*)$)`

It says: There needs to be at most one `a` from here (the beginning) until the end.

Combining [**lookaheads**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) and [**backreferences**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#usebackrefinregex):

```
^([abc])((?!\1)([abc])((?!\1)(?!\3)[abc])?)?$
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to round out the collection:

```
^(?:([abc])(?!.*\1))+$
```

Want to handle a larger set of characters?  No problem:

```
^(?:([abcdefgh])(?!.*\1))+$
```

**EDIT:** Apparently I misread the question; you're not validating individual strings like `"abc"` and `"ba"`, you're trying to find whole-word matches in a larger string.  Here's how I would do that:

```
\b(?:([abc])(?![abc]*\1))+\b
```

The tricky part is making sure the lookahead doesn't look beyond the end of the word that's currently being matched.  For example, if I had left the lookahead as `(?!.*\1)`, it would fail to match the `abc` in `abc za` because the lookahead would incorrectly flag the `a` in `za` as a duplicate of the `a` in `abc`.  Allowing the lookahead to look only at valid characters (`[abc]*`) keeps it on a sufficiently short leash.  And if there are invalid characters in the current word, it's not the lookahead's job to spot them anyway.

(Thanks to [Honest Abe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546187/how-to-match-any-combination-of-letters-using-regex/13547282#comment20671757_13547282) for bringing this back to my attention.)

Comment: This would be my choice to upvote, but the example doesn't seem to work as is. Does the example work with a certain language? I got it to work by changing it to `\b(?:([abc])(?!\1))+\b`

Comment: I was assuming the regex would be applied to each string in isolation ("abc", "cb", "abz", etc.), but it looks like the OP wants to pluck whole-word matches from a larger string.  So you're right, I should have used `\b` instead of the anchors, but you can't just remove the `.*` from the lookahead.  That correctly filters out `aab` but not `aba`.  See my edit for the corrected regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?=(.*a.*)?$)(?=(.*b.*)?$)(?=(.*c.*)?$)[abc]{,3}$
```

The anchored look-aheads limit the number of occurrences of each letter to one.

Comment: This also matches the "ab" in "abz", and "aab" and "cc". So this is not correct. (I just tested in the Patterns regex app for Mac)

Comment: In the Patterns app this only works when I select both the single-line AND multi-line options - which I'm not sure makes much sense and may be a bug in Patterns.

Comment: In English, this RegEx says: Be empty OR end in `a`, `b` and `c` at the same time, which is of course impossible.

Comment: @phant0m Actually it doesn't say that at all. The look aheads each say  "there must be either 1 or 0 "a" somewhere in the whole input.

Comment: No, it did not and it doesn't say that after your edit either. Now, it says: The string is either empty OR it contains at least an `a`, a `b` and a `c`. (Neglecting that `{,3}` is invalid)

Comment: Maybe it's better if I said *why* I came to the above conclusion: `(?=(.*a.*)?$)` This lookahead starts *right after* the beginning of the string. Since the lookahead has a dollar sign at the end, `(.*a.*)?` must match everything from the beginning of the line until the end. Since it's got a question mark the line *might* be empty, OR there has to be at least one `a`. There is nothing that prevents it from having multiple `a`s. Because the other patterns work in similar, the string must contain an `a`, a `b` and a `c` if it's not empty. I hope that clears things up, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^([abc])((?!\1)([abc]))?((?!(\1|\2))([abc]))?$
```

Check in [**regexpal**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28%5Babc%5D%29%28%28?!.%2a%5C1%29%28%5Babc%5D%29%29?%28%28?!.%2a%28%5C1%7C%5C2%29%29%28%5Babc%5D%29%29?%24&input=a%0Aabc%0Aab%0Aac%0Aab%0Aacb%0Aabb%0Aaa%0Abb%0Acaa%0Acbc%0Aabx%0Abab)

Answer (score 0):

I linked it in comment (this is sort of a dupe of [How can I find repeated characters with a regex in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664194/how-can-i-find-repeated-characters-with-a-regex-in-java)).. but to be more specific.. the regex:

```
(\w)\1+
```

Will match any two or more of the same character. Negate that and you have your regex.

Comment: He only wants a, b, and c - so replacing \w with [abc] seems like the obvious choice - but the negation of that would still match "abz" and "x" - so it's not a final solution.