# how to match specific combination of 2 letters with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

given this set of letters

> xx | af | an | bf | bn | cf | cn

how can I see if, given two characters, they match against one of the above?

I could easily hardcode the solution with a switch case, but I think regex is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Try this solution: 
Here's [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546187/how-to-match-any-combination-of-letters-using-regex)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wrote the regular expression yourself as stated previously, you could simplify it to...

```
var re = /xx|[abc][fn]/
```

Comment: Or even `/xx|[abc][fn]/`.

Comment: All of the answers are correct, but I'd choose this because it really matches the semantics of my use case: either xx or a possible combination between the characters abc with fn (they have specific meanings in my code). Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You basically wrote the regex yourself:

`xx|af|an|bf|bn|cf|cn`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
// regex to match your words
var re = /\b(xx|af|an|bf|bn|cf|cn)\b/g; 

// your text string
var str = 'as ww zx af ad we re an ana ';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/wY7vY1/3)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^(xx|af|an|bf|bn|cf|cn)$

xx  => Correct
af  => Correct
aff => Incorrect
kk  => Incorrect
```

**[Live demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YyeJtYP3NzICNGt4)**

Comment: Since the specification was "given two letters", the anchors seem unnecessary.