# Is there a way regex will match all the combinations of the tokens in `|` operator

Tags: regex, nand2tetris

I am doing a parser for [nand2tetris](https://www.nand2tetris.org/) project. I want to check if the destination field is either `M|D|MD|A|AM|AD|AMD` and their different ways of combinations like `MA` not only `AM`.

```
^(M|D|MD|A|AM|AD|AMD)\s*=$
```

This regex correctly matches `AM=`, but not `MA=`.

I don't want to list out all the possible combinations of those tokens, is there a way to do it simply?

Comment: I think we can list the regex matches in orders, `^(M|D|DM|A|AM|AD|ADM)\s*=7$` and also the input token in order, that will match

Comment: This question is likely a duplicate, but this is the regex you need `^([ADM])(?:(?!\1)([ADM])(?:(?!\1|\2)[ADM])?)?\s*=$` https://regex101.com/r/SNhJpf/2

Comment: Thanks @Nick. Can you show the link for the duplicate and mark this question as duplicate?

Comment: I've been searching for it but can't find it. I seem to recall seeing something like this in the last couple of days (it was a more generic `(.)(?!\1)(.)(?!\1|\2).`) but I can't find it again.

Comment: Nick, post the answer so at least we can upvote you m8.

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13546187/9758194) is a duplicate post? If you guys are searching for one =). I believe it would boild down to `^(?!(?:.\B)*(.)(?:\B.)*\1)[AMD]+\b=$` then

Comment: You must have been confident I would fix my answer as it was wrong at the time. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
^(?=[MDA]+$)(?!.?(.).?\1).{1,3}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QnsZ7I/7/)

The negative lookahead attempts to match two `"M"`'s, two `"D"`'s or two `"A"`'s.

The positive lookahead merely restricts the characters in the string to `"M"`, `"D"` and `"A"`. That was not necessary but it allows me to use `.`'s in the rest, rather than `(?![MDA]?([MDA])[MDA]?...)`, which may make it easier to read.